# Django HttpResponseRedirect with int parameter

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I want to pass an int parameter (`user_id`) from a login view to another view. Is that possible within an `HttpResponseRedirect`? I try something like this:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect("/profile/?user_id=user.id")
```

While my urlconf is:

```
(r'^profile/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', '...')
```

But I don't know if that's the right way. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you can use `next` argument of `login` view ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login)). It will be the simpliest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, that's clearly not the right way, because the URL you create does not match the one in your urlconf.

The correct way to do this is to rely on Django to do it for you. If you give your URL definition a name:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('', 
    url(r'^profile/(?P\d+)/$', ' ...', name='profile'),
)
```

then you can use `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse` to generate that URL with your arguments:

```
redirect_url = reverse('profile', args=[user.id])
return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
```

Note it's better to use kwargs rather than args in your URLs, but I've kept it as you had originally.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I combined the above answers by doing:

```
url = reverse('profile', kwargs={ 'user_id': user.id })
return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

and

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', '...', name='profile')
```

and it worked perfectly.

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That is possible but it's better to reverse the URL and then redirect to it:

```
url = reverse('name_of_url', kwargs={ 'user_id': user.id })
return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

You should make sure that your URL conf has a named parameter in it (in my above example it's a parameter called `user_id`.